# How to determine when function overrides another in the chain of inheritance?

Tags: ptvs

I am using PTVS assemblies to generate strongly typed bindings for a Python library. I've got an instance of `ModuleAnalysis`, which I use to perform various queries about guessed types in Python code.

At this moment I stumbled upon a need in my C# output to explicitly mark all overriden methods with `override` keyword. However, I can't seem to figure how to determine if the one of the parent classes already has a member with a same name, that is being overriden.

Here is a sample of what I am trying to convert:

```
class Base:
    def virt(self):
        print("Base.virt")

class A(Base):   
    def virt(self):
        super().virt()

    def non_virt(self):
        pass
```

When processing A's virt, I tried to do this:

```
analysis.GetValuesByIndex("super()." + node.Name, node.Body.EndIndex)
```

Here, `ModuleAnalysis analysis` and `FunctionDefinition node`. I also tried `Body.StartIndex` and `"super(A, self)." + node.Name`.

Unexpectedly, this gives no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is going to be to look at the MRO of the class and inspect each base class definition.

This sequence of steps *should* work most of the time - PTVS doesn't pretend to do static analysis quality type inferencing, so there are many situations where it "gives up" (particularly when cross-module imports start getting complicated):

1. Find the type of `self` within the function (make sure the location is within the function scope)
2. Find `ClassInfo.Mro`
3. Find `self` in the MRO (should be first), and then after that check each `ClassInfo.ClassDefinition` node to see if it contains the function, or `BuiltinClassInfo.PythonType.GetMember()` for an imported definition